# One form inside another <div> becomes unclickable

Tags: html, css, forms

I want a html page having two forms, one for Log In positioned at the center (horizontally and vertically) of the page, and another Sign Up form positioned at the top right corner.

I divided both forms in two separated divs to apply styles.

The problem is that the Sign Up form becomes unclickable in its input tags.

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  /*whatever width you want*/
}

.login-form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.login-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-form input[type="password"],
.login-form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.signup-form {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.signup-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form input[type="password"],
.signup-form input[type="text"],
.signup-form input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signup-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="login-form">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>

        <form action="/auth" method="POST">
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="signup-form">
  <h1>Signup Form</h1>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="usernames" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</div>
```

Why the Sign Up form becomes unclickable?

PD: I use the outter, middle and inner divs to center the Log in form vertically and horizontally.

Edit: I used the base code from https://codeshack.io/basic-login-system-nodejs-express-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `.outer` takes whole page width and is above `.signup-form`.

Few ways to solve:

1. Re-design elements to not be overlapping
2. Add `.signup-form {z-index: 10; position: relative;}`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, .3);
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  /*whatever width you want*/
}

.login-form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.login-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-form input[type="password"],
.login-form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.signup-form {
  /* Added code */
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  /* End of added code */

  background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.signup-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form input[type="password"],
.signup-form input[type="text"],
.signup-form input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signup-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="login-form">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>

        <form action="/auth" method="POST">
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="signup-form">
  <h1>Signup Form</h1>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="usernames" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I forgot the outer class takes the whole width. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because `.outer` "covers" it. If you just want to center the login form (and stick sign up to the right) use `flex`.

Notice that in small screens, the signup form overlaps the login form so you should probably need to design it differently at some resolution point.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login-form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.login-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-form input[type="password"],
.login-form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.signup-form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.signup-form h1 {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form input[type="password"],
.signup-form input[type="text"],
.signup-form input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signup-form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #535b63;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="login-form">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>

    <form action="/auth" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="signup-form">
    <h1>Signup Form</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="username" name="usernames" placeholder="Username" required>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Password" required>
      <input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```